# Reverse Vertical Column Scrolling Issue in iOS

Tags: html, ios, scroll, reverse

I have 2 columns in my HTML page. The first column scrolls up, the second (right) is scrolling down (reverse).

So far it's doing what it's supposed to do. In all browsers on OS its working fine. But in the mobile browsers (iOS Safari and iOS Chrome) the second, right column is buggy. Its a bit shaking and its not scrolling that smooth compared to the first column.

I'm not the best coder but here is the `:` [codepen-demo](https://codepen.io/schrau6e/pen/oNmXpJX)

Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.